# iOS: accept multiple object types as a paramenter (id)object?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, object

I want to create a method that will accept a UIButton, UIImageView, or any other object as a parameter. I have tried the following using the id type,

```
-(void)shiftObject:(id)object {
      object.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20);
}
```

but the xcode static error checker flagged it right away. Is there a way that this can be done? I think I am on the right track using the id type, but I'm unsure where to go from here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really use this with "any other object", just "any other object that has a frame property".

So, try casting to something with a frame, like UIView. All of the objects you mentioned inherit from UIView, and therefore have the frame property.

```
-(void)shiftObject:(id)object {
      ((UIView*)object).frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20);
}
```

Comment: thanks, evan. I should have specified that I intended to use it only on objects with a frame. This works very well for the object types that I mentioned, as well as many others. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can cast your object to the correct type:

```
((UIButton*)object).frame = ...
```

or you can call the setter without the dot notation

```
[object setFrame:...];
```

You should check if your object is of the correct type before or if it responds to the selector you want to send.